# How can I use Piwik in Ionic 2?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, matomo

For instance, in iOS, I can

```
PiwikTracker.sharedInstance().sendEventWithCategory("Page1", action: "Page1Action", name: "\(page1.id)", value: 1)
```

How can I do the same thing in Ionic 2?

Comment: Did you see my comment there: https://forum.piwik.org/t/how-can-i-use-piwik-in-an-ionic-2-project/19656 ? Did you find a solution?

Comment: @geoHeil Ah, I forgot to reply you that my problem has been solved. Thanks for your help. Plus, maybe we just leave this question here for somebody else?

Comment: sure. How did you solve it? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: I don't know if we have the same problem. Just some advises: Check versions of your plugins, check your piwik IDs or URIs, check quotation marks, etc. Sometimes ancient versions may be better. Sometimes a plugin may only work with a certain version of other stuff.

Comment: thx. Just realized after some minutes that changing the date selector results in a display of the desired metrics.

Comment: Do you use Angulartics2? can you help me get started here https://github.com/geoHeil/ionic2Angulartics2 I do face some strange issues